# How to create correct JsonArray in Java using JSONObject using servlet

Tags: java, arrays, json, servlets

how can I create a JSON Object like the following, in Java using JSONObject ?

```
    [
  {
    "title": "ZAKI",
    "start": "2010-05-01",
    "placemarks": [
      {
        "polyline": [
          {
            "lat": 48.22467264956519,
            "lon": 16.32568359375
          },
          {
            "lat": 47.517200697839414,
            "lon": 18.984375
          },
          {
            "lat": 45.84410779560204,
            "lon": 15.9521484375
          },
          {
            "lat": 48.22467264956519,
            "lon": 16.32568359375
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "point": {
          "lat": 48.22467264956519,
          "lon": 16.32568359375
        }
      },
      {
        "point": {
          "lat": 47.517200697839414,
          "lon": 18.984375
        }
      },
      {
        "point": {
          "lat": 45.84410779560204,
          "lon": 15.9521484375
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm using servlet.

This my servlet code

```
JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < listDataTracking.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                EntityTracking dataTracking = listDataTracking.get(i);

                if (dataTracking.getIdTracking() == null) {
                    obj.put("Id", "");
                } else {
                    obj.put("Id", dataTracking.getIdTracking());
                    obj.put("title", dataTracking.getUser_name().getUserName().toUpperCase());
                    obj.put("start", sdf.format(dataTracking.getTglSend()));
//                                       
                    String lat = "";
                    String lon = "";
                    String jamSend = "";
                    Long id = 0l;
//                    

                    String queryStmnt_geoTracking = "SELECT entityGeoTracking.id FROM EntityGeoTracking entityGeoTracking "
                            + "WHERE entityGeoTracking.idTracking.idTracking=\"" + dataTracking.getIdTracking() + "\"";
                    javax.persistence.Query query_geoTracking = em.createQuery(queryStmnt_geoTracking);
                    System.out.println("Isi queryStmnt_geoTracking" + queryStmnt_geoTracking);
                    List<EntityGeoTracking> cekid = query_geoTracking.getResultList();
                    if (cekid.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Isi cekid == null");
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Isi cekid" + cekid);
                    EntityGeoTracking dataGeoTraking = em.find(EntityGeoTracking.class, cekid);
                    if (lat.isEmpty()) {

                        lat = dataGeoTraking.getGetLatitude();
                    }
                    if (lon.isEmpty()) {
                        lon = dataGeoTraking.getGetLongitude();
                    }
                    if (id == 0l) {
                        id = dataGeoTraking.getId();
                    }
                    if (jamSend.isEmpty()) {
                        jamSend = dataGeoTraking.getJamSend();
                    }
                    System.out.println("chek value lat, lon, id, jamSend" + lat + "" + lon + "" + id + "" + jamSend);

                   javax.json.JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
                            .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("polyline", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("lat", lat)
                            .add("lon", lon)))
                            .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("point", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("lat", lat)
                            .add("lon", lon)))
                           .build();


                    obj.put("placemarks", value);

                }



                arrayObj.add(obj);
            }

            em.close();

            JSONObject rows = new JSONObject();

//            rows.put("results", arrayObj);//results
//            rows.put("results", listDataTracking.size());//results
//            rows.put("rows", arrayObj);
//            writer.print(rows.toString());
//            rows.put("", listDataTracking.size());//results
            rows.put("", arrayObj);
            System.out.println(" List : " + arrayObj.toString());
            writer.print(arrayObj);
            writer.close();

//            }
//            br.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

My outPut JSON format

```
   [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "title": "ZAKI",
    "start": "2016-06-15",
    "placemarks": [
      {
        "polyline": {
          "lat": {
            "chars": "-6.2206080",
            "string": "-6.2206080",
            "valueType": "STRING"
          },
          "lon": {
            "chars": "106.7810640",
            "string": "106.7810640",
            "valueType": "STRING"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "point": {
          "lat": {
            "chars": "-6.2206080",
            "string": "-6.2206080",
            "valueType": "STRING"
          },
          "lon": {
            "chars": "106.7810640",
            "string": "106.7810640",
            "valueType": "STRING"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried it many times but I've been unsuccessful. Please help!

Comment: Whether you are using servlets or not seems to be irrelevant here. Assuming you load the correct data (you can check that yourself, e.g. by debugging your code) the question seems to be about how to construct the JSON array you want to. That said you should check what `results[0].toString();` etc. actually returns. `entityGeoTracking.getLatitude` (that's a weird property name btw) might not just return a number or string but some wrapper object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "title": "ZAKI",
    "start": "2010-05-01",
    "placemarks": [
        {
            "polyline": [
                {
                    "lat": 48.2246726495652,
                    "lon": 16.32568359375
                },
                {
                    "lat": 47.5172006978394,
                    "lon": 18.984375
                },
                {
                    "lat": 45.844107795602,
                    "lon": 15.9521484375
                },
                {
                    "lat": 48.2246726495652,
                    "lon": 16.32568359375
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "point": {
                "lat": 48.2246726495652,
                "lon": 16.32568359375
            }
        },
        {
            "point": {
                "lat": 47.5172006978394,
                "lon": 18.984375
            }
        },
        {
            "point": {
                "lat": 45.844107795602,
                "lon": 15.9521484375
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

First of All use [some formatting tool](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to format your json so that you can easily understand the difference in expected vs actual output.

for the polyline object you should have an array rather than object with in a object.

```
Json.createObjectBuilder().add("polyline", 
                              Json.createObjectBuilder().add("lat", lat).add("lon", lon))
                              )
```